# bash. read input "words" string between symbols

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have this kind of input in a bash I'm creating:

cat-dog-lion

I need my program to do something with each word like this

```
`if first_word == "cat" 
 do stuff 
    if second_word == "dog" 
    do other stuff`
```

How should I do this? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

BASH solution:

```
input='cat-dog-lion'
if [[ "${input}" =~ "^cat-?" ]]
then
  echo "do stuff"
  if [[ "${input}" =~ "^cat-dog-?" ]]
  then
    echo "do other stuff"
  fi
fi
```

If wanna AWK solution here it is:

```
awk -F'-' '{ if ($1=="cat") { print("do stuff"); if ($2=="dog") print("do other stuff"); } }'
```

Test:

```
$ echo 'cat-dog-lion' | awk -F'-' '{ if ($1=="cat") { print("do stuff"); if ($2=="dog") print("do other stuff"); } }'
do stuff
do other stuff
$ echo 'cat-wolf-lion' | awk -F'-' '{ if ($1=="cat") { print("do stuff"); if ($2=="dog") print("do other stuff"); } }'
do stuff
$ echo 'lynx-dog-lion' | awk -F'-' '{ if ($1=="cat") { print("do stuff"); if ($2=="dog") print("do other stuff"); } }'
$
```

Answer (score -1):

If the input field separator is a `-`, you should call `read` with IFS set appropriately:

```
echo 'cat-dog-lion' | { IFS=- read first_word second_word third_word other_stuff
case $first_word in
cat) ... ;;
*)   ... ;;
esac
case $second_word in
...
esac
...
}
```

Note that the enclosing `{` and `}` are important, as the variables go out of scope after the closing `{`.  (The pipe creates a subprocess in which the variables exist.)